# Issue concerning the upgrade of an Ember app to the version 2.14

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, upgrade, ember-cli

I have an issue with the new version of ember (2.14). 
I upgraded my project using this [help](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases).
I fixed some issues that I had, for example:

> Transform -> DS.Transform.

But there is one error that I cannot solve, it's a warning that show up in the debbuging console:

```js
DEPRECATION: Using "_lookupFactory" is deprecated. Please use
             container.factoryFor instead. [deprecation id: container-lookupFactory]
             See http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_migrating-from-_lookupfactory-to-factoryfor for more details.
        at logDeprecationStackTrace (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:32785:21)
        at HANDLERS.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:33003:9)
        at raiseOnDeprecation (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:32815:14)
        at HANDLERS.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:33003:9)
        at invoke (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:33015:9)
        at deprecate (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:32869:24)
        at Container.lookupFactory (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:29145:54)
        at Class._lookupFactory (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:57166:33)
        at Locale._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:92841:32)
logDeprecationStackTrace @ deprecate.js:116
HANDLERS.(anonymous function) @ handlers.js:14
raiseOnDeprecation @ deprecate.js:128
HANDLERS.(anonymous function) @ handlers.js:14
invoke @ handlers.js:26
deprecate @ deprecate.js:182
lookupFactory @ container.js:43
_lookupFactory @ container_proxy.js:26
_compileTemplate @ locale.js:116
getCompiledTemplate @ locale.js:60
t @ i18n.js:47
compute @ boolean-to-colored-yes-no.js:9
compute @ references.js:459
value @ references.js:70
compute @ reference.js:287
value @ reference.js:256
initialize @ reference.js:337
peek @ reference.js:311
evaluate @ runtime.js:6615
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:6562
evaluate @ runtime.js:202
next @ runtime.js:6115
execute @ runtime.js:6090
resume @ runtime.js:6081
handleException @ runtime.js:6360
handleException @ runtime.js:6551
_throw @ runtime.js:6245
evaluate @ runtime.js:411
execute @ runtime.js:6232
rerender @ runtime.js:5642
_this.render @ renderer.js:68
exports.runInTransaction @ ember-metal.js:693
_renderRoots @ renderer.js:335
_renderRootsTransaction @ renderer.js:373
_revalidate @ renderer.js:412
invokeWithOnError @ backburner.js:271
flush @ backburner.js:157
flush @ backburner.js:320
end @ backburner.js:399
run @ backburner.js:478
join @ backburner.js:491
run$1.join @ ember-metal.js:4456
(anonymous) @ has_element.js:18
exports.flaggedInstrument @ ember-metal.js:3883
handleEvent @ has_element.js:17
exports.default._emberMetal.Mixin.create._Mixin$create.handleEvent @ view_support.js:260
_bubbleEvent @ event_dispatcher.js:267
(anonymous) @ event_dispatcher.js:201
dispatch @ jquery.js:5206
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:5014
```

I already checked, I don't have any call to _lookupFactory.

I'm quite new to ember and Javascript in general.

Comment: It looks like this is showing up in your dependencies, as it is an internal API for addon developers.  Have you updated your app's dependencies?  Try running npm update --save

Comment: I already tried it, but the problem was coming from an out-dated add-on, thank you for your time anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably coming from i18n addon. You can see in stack trace:

> t @ i18n.js:47

It looks like addon owners already fixed this issue in January. You can see related pull request: https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/pull/431/files

The file which probably resulted in causing deprecation was: addon/utils/locale.js - Line of Code: 33:

```
const defaultConfig = this.owner._lookupFactory('ember-i18n@config:zh');
```

Please upgrade version of i18n you depend on in your project.

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't think that could be an issue, you help me a lot!